# Trouble calling a method from a class

Tags: c#, class, methods

Can anybody help me with this?:
I'm trying call a method from a my class "numbers" to show that if the entered number is over 50, on button click a message box shows displaying "high" but if it's below 50 it displays "low". 
I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong here. 
This is the code from my class:

```
    private int number; 
    private string getNumber(int num)
    {

        number = num;
        return number.ToString();
    }

        public int numProperty
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { number = value; }
    }

     public void isHighorlow()
        {    
            if (number >=50)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

        }
```

Note: the int "number" is property that gets it's value from a text box too. 
& here is the code from my form:

```
     numbers info = new numbers();
     private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
      info.numProperty = Convert.ToInt32(numberBOX.Text);
      info.isHighorlow = Messagebox.Show = ("High");
    }
```

I know that I've not added the "low" bit yet because i'm still trying to see how this works.  Sorry if it seems confusing as i'm still learning c#. 
I get the error message: cannot assign isHighorlow because it's part of a method group. 
And I also realise it's much easier if I just do an if statement on the textbox, but I'm practising Classes and Methods so I'm trying to do it this way. 
thanks.

Comment: isHighorlow is a method not a property.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to call that method to show if the property is over 50 or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsHighOrLow should be as follows

```
    public bool isHighorlow()
    {    
        if (number >=50)
        {

           return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

And in button click

```
if (info.isHighorlow){
//say high
} else
{
// say low
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
public string isHighorlow(int number)
{    
    if (number >=50)
    { 
         return "High";
    }
    else
    {
         return "Low";
    }
}


numbers info = new numbers();
private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  Messagebox.Show(info.isHighorlow(Convert.ToInt32(numberBOX.Text)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

isHighorLow is a method, not a property.

MessageBox.Show is a method.

Not sure what you are trying to do but it should be :

```
 if(info.isHigh(Convert.ToInt32(numberBox.Text)))
   Messagebox.Show("High");
  else
    Messagebox.Show("Low");
```

Meaning you have a method isHigh like so:

```
public bool isHigh()
{
   return number>=50
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code this way:

```
private int _number; 

private string GetNumber(int number)
{
    _number = number;
    return number .ToString();
}

public int Number
{
    get { return _number; }
    set { _number = value; }
}

public string IsHigh()
{   
    get { if (number >= 50) return true; }
}

numbers info = new numbers();
private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    info.Number = Convert.ToInt32(numberBOX.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(info.IsHigh ? "High" : "Low");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your class you have defined `void isHighorlow()`.
This means that you have a method that returns nothing.
Of course such method cannot be used on the left part of an expression like you have done.

Probably you want to write in your class

```
public bool isHighorlow() 
{     
    if (number >=50) 
    { 
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return false; 
    }
```

}

in this way you declare a method that return True if the internal value is >= 50 or false otherwise.
Now, in your form you can use the method in this way

```
Messagebox.Show(info.isHighorlow() ? "High" : "Low");
```

However, if the requirement is simply to return a flag for true or false, it is better to use a read only property changing the class code in this way

```
public bool isHighorlow() 
{     
    get
    {
        return (number >=50 ? true : false);
    } 
    // No set, read only
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer: double check `boolean` and associated constants per C#)

isHighOrLow doesn't do anything at all.  Perhaps this would be better:

```
     public boolean isHigh()
        {    
            if (number >=50)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Or, more concisely:

```
     public boolean isHigh()
        {    
            return number >=50;
        }
```

When you call it, this might be closer to what you need:

```
     numbers info = new numbers();
     private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
      info.numProperty = Convert.ToInt32(numberBOX.Text);
      if (info.isHigh())
      {
        Messagebox.Show("High");
      }
      else
      {
        Messagebox.Show("Low");
      }
    }
```